# SVG path - Add and subtract || lasso selection tool in canvas

Tags: svg, html5-canvas

I want to combine two SVG paths such that

1.Both paths will be there but, at the area of intersection, there will be no strokes.

2.Second path will be excluded and there will be a complete stroke

See image at http://s18.postimg.org/et4m803rd/shape_combinations.jpg

I want similar function also in HTML5 canvas.
The purpose of this scenario is to implement a lasso selection tool (freehand selection) similar to that of photoshop, with **Ctrl** and **Alt** options for adding and subtracting selection [ + some other functions ].

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?  This sounds a little bit like a homework assignment.

The first one is easy to replicate.  Just draw the two circles with the stroke, then draw them again in the same place without the stroke.

You can achieve the second shape (the "pacman") by drawing a purple circle on the right that is clipped by a circle that is in the same position as the left (black) circle.

Comment: Thank you.In the second solution, the stroke will be a problem. Please see the updated question

Comment: For the "lasso" thing, you are going to have to build up your path shape yourself by adding and subtracting rectangles.  There is no shortcut to that.